# Sensor types in bread production

Tags: sensor, identification, production

[image]

What is the name of these two sensors and what function do they perform?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Industrial sensors in that that style typically use one of three technologies:

- **Inductive proximity**: These are good for sensing ferrous metals and can detect non-ferrous metals such as aluminium but at reduced range.
- **Photo-sensor**: The most common shine a red LED light or LASER to illuminate the target and have a sensor to measure the reflected light. There are a variety of techniques used for background suppression and distance measurement.
- **Capacitive proximity**: These use two small plates on the front surface of the sensor as a very poor capacitor (as the plates have no overlap). When a suitable material comes within range there is capacitive coupling between the first plate and the object and between the object and the second plate. The sensor can detect this.

For sensing bread dough we can rule out inductive type as bread is not metallic. We can probably rule out photo-sensors as there is no visible light spot on either photo. That leaves capacitive as most likely as the water content of the dough will provide enough capacitance to trigger the sensor.

The sensors are usually 24 V DC powered (as is normal in most industrial controls). The sensitivity adjustment potentiometer can be seen in the upper photograph.

The function of the sensors might be simply to trigger the product counter or they could be used to trigger the start of an operation when a part is in position. As mounted in the lower photo a pneumatic pusher cylinder is visible on each of the two lanes before the sensor so I suspect that the pieces of dough are flipped over or folded at those stations. There isn't enough context in the upper photo for me to determine the purpose of that station.

Comment: There are also [ultrasonic sensors](https://www.baumer.com/us/en/product-overview/object-detection/ultrasonic-sensors/c/281) in this design.

Comment: @nanash1: True, and I've used them in the past. (I used "typically" in the first sentence to allow me to wriggle out of all the other types.) We're probably missing LIDAR and smart camera / vision sensors too.